# Javascript switch with global variable

Tags: javascript, scope, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a global variable with a switch statement but the value of the variable is not changing. Perhaps a scope problem?

I need a switch statement to cycle through each case one by one, but the "i" variable keeps resetting to 1 every time I view it in the console.

Why is this happening?

**THE CODE**

```
var i = 0;

switch(i){
    case 0:
        i+=1;
        console.log(i);
        break;
    case 1:
        i+=1;
        console.log(i);
        break;
}
```

and so on...

*edit:* Great support from everybody below, thank you very much.

Comment: Unanswerable at this time - the code you've posted wont exhibit the behaviour you describe. Reproduce the problem using a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), not a switch.

Comment: switch will evaluate i just once and will run just once, this is not a loop

Comment: _"I need a switch statement to cycle through each case one by one"_: that's not how `switch` works. You will always get `1` because that is the case that is matched.

Comment: Also, if you want `i` to be a global variable, don't declare it with `var`.

Comment: @JeremyJackson, you can define a global with `var`, in fact if you use `use strict` it's a requirement.

Comment: Trying to [unroll a loop](http://www.fatagnus.com/unrolling-your-loop-for-better-performance-in-javascript/) a la Tom Duff?

Comment: @Andy TIL. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you all, I've revised it and found a solution to my problem, ive simply replaced the switch, not with a loop but an if. The reason i was trying a switch is because i've used it in a somewhat similar situation to this and was stubborn to believe it would work but its all part of learning, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This behaves this way, because switch is working like:

1. Before iteration it stores your condition.
2. After that it takes decision.

Switch is not like "use it async", it is running only 1 time when it is invoked.

You can workaround this for example by using loop.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```js
switch (Number(i)) {
  // cases
}
```

I had the same problem and had already corrected this once, but had forgotten.